# JAVA: Regexp on user-defined tokens

Tags: java, regex, customization

I need to run a regexp on a set of user-defined tokens.

For example, I've a string like this: 
    `TOK3 TOK1 TOK2 TOK2 TOK4 TOK3` // example string

and by using a regexp like this:
  `(TOK1|TOK2)+` // regexp

I'd like to capture the sequence of tokens: `TOK1 TOK2 TOK2` in my example string.

Now, **regexp** usually work on a sequence of characters, so my problem is slightly different in the sense that my tokens are not characters but strings. My tokens could be composed by two or more characters. Furthermore, my software should be able to detect that the regexp in the example matches the string at the position (1, 4).

For the moment, I solved the problem by mapping each token to a char in the ASCII alphabet and running the regexp after removing the spaces.

However, I'm not completely satsfied with this solution and I was wondering if there is a better one. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Spaces in the regexp are only needed to separate the tokens. They don't really mean that spaces are mandatory between tokens.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean by custom defined tokens with an example / code? Like a collection of strings?

Comment: Basically that the pattern is not a sequence of chars but a sequence of Strings. Probably the right term is not custom, but customized. My apologies. However, each token should be considered an atomic entity as a char.

Comment: Why are you first removing the whitespaces instead of including them in your regex?

Comment: Because in my implementation I map each token to a char and then I match the mapped regexp agains the map matched string.

e.g. The pattern `(TOK1|TOK2)+`  is mapped for isntance to `"(a|b)+"`. While the example string is mapped in `"c a b b d c"`. The latter, afeter removing spaces is `"cabbdc"`. Now the pattern can match the example string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing the positions of all the spaces and using this to translate the string position to the token position?

Far from as elegant as a straight regex, but it's an idea.

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> spaces = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
String regex = "(?<=^| )((TOK1|TOK2)( |$))+";
String str = "TOK3 TOK1 TOK2 TOK2 TOK4 TOK3";
int c = 0;
spaces.put(0, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
   if (str.charAt(i) == ' ')
     spaces.put(i, ++c);
}
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
   System.out.println("start = " + spaces.floorEntry(m.start()).getValue());
   System.out.println("finish = " + spaces.floorEntry(m.end()).getValue());
}
```

Another option would be `String.split`:

```
String str = "TOK3 TOK1 TOK2 TOK2 TOK4 TOK3";
String[] arr = str.split(" "); // maybe consider using \\s or \\s+ instead
int start = -1;
String match = "";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
   if (arr[i].matches("(TOK1|TOK2)"))
   {
      if (start == -1)
         start = i;
      match += ((match.length() != 0) ? " " : "") + arr[i];
   }
   else if (start != -1)
   {
      System.out.println(match);
      System.out.println("start = " + start);
      System.out.println("finish = " + i);
      match = "";
      start = -1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Following your example, this should work fine:

```
(?:(?:TOK1|TOK2|...)(?: |$))+
```

The Matcher#start method would give you the position of the beginning of the match.

Still, as it seems really easy, I feel like I'm missing something in your question...

Comment: But the start() method and the end() one would give me the position of the first char matching the pattern, no the token position. Alhough I could segment the string and count how many token remained at the left of the match... :)

Comment: Well the first char's position if the token's position too, isn't it? And if you want each token's position, I guess `TOK1|TOK2` would be even easier. Can a token be some substring of another token?

Comment: Not really. For instance, the pattern matches at (5, 19) if we consider chars, but position (1, 4) if we consider tokens (and ignore spaces). In certain cases tokens could be substring of other tokens.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I'll give it a thought. (How do you currently replace the tokens? Wouldn't you be fooled by substrings?)

Comment: Actually, I've spaces (in the pattern and example string) which show me the boundary of tokens. In this way the mapping process is simplified. Than I use a lookup table (token (String) -> char).